# Python error: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 85: invalid start byte

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am using python2.7 and lxml. My code is as below

```
import urllib
from lxml import html

def get_value(el):
    return get_text(el, 'value') or el.text_content()

response = urllib.urlopen('http://www.edmunds.com/dealerships/Texas/Frisco/DavidMcDavidHondaofFrisco/fullsales-504210667.html').read()
dom = html.fromstring(response)

try:
    description = get_value(dom.xpath("//div[@class='description item vcard']")[0].xpath(".//p[@class='sales-review-paragraph loose-spacing']")[0])
except IndexError, e:
    description = ''
```

The code crashes inside the try, giving an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 85: invalid start byte
```

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: ouldn�t be

I have tried using a lot of techniques including .encode('utf8'), but none does solve the problem. I have 2 question:

1. How to solve this problem
2. How can my app crash when the problem code is between a try except

Comment: Post the whole traceback, not just the last line of it.

Comment: Snapshot for @Marcin's answer. Checking encode of a webpage is really useful to debug encoding errors. 

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jVHTy.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The page is being served up with `charset=ISO-8859-1`. Decode from that to unicode.

[[image: Snapshot of details from a browser. Credit @Old Panda]]

Comment: @mangobug Unless you show the actual code including the decode call, no-one can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Your except clause only handles exceptions of the IndexError type. The problem was a UnicodeDecodeError, which is not an IndexError - so the exception is not handled by that except clause.

It's also not clear what 'get_value' does, and that may well be where the actual problem is arising.

Comment: That's not much help because now we just have a 'get_text' function that we don't understand. And we don't have the full traceback yet either. You need to provide full context otherwise people just have to guess at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. - skip chars on Error, or decode it correctly to unicode.
2. - you only catch IndexError, not UnicodeDecodeError

Answer (score 0):

1. decode the response to unicode, properly handling errors (ignore on error) before parsing with fromhtml.
2. catch the UnicodeDecodeError, or all errors.

Comment: The answer is not to catch all errors. That's how you hide bugs in your program.